# Can't install Copula package on Mac or Linux

Tags: r, package, cran

I have this problem with the **Copula** package: I can't install it on my Macbook, nor another linux system.

I think I used the right command but I could not find the installed package in the lib. Any ideas?

```
> install.packages('/tmp/RtmpYZDYzC/downloaded_packages/copula_0.999-10.tar.gz',repos = NULL,type='source' )
Installing package into ‘/home/rstudio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
```

Comment: Do you have any error message?

Comment: @Pascal no, no error information. Seems success but actually not.

Comment: So, what happens when you do `library('copula')`?

Comment: @Thomas nothing happens. Can't find this package.

Comment: @NingChang "Nothing happens" is highly unlikely. If there is an error, you should report it verbatim in an edit to your question.

Comment: it can't be used if you're using OS X Mavericks (OS X 10.9.5). the R release is not available. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/copula/index.html